# How can I remove spot stains from this hardwood floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

I recently found hardwood flooring under some carpet, and I want to keep it. The problem is it has some dark spot in it that I don't like. Is sanding the only way to remove these spots?

[image: floor spots]

[image: Floor spots 2]

Comment: "sand or restore"? Those are the same thing. Even if you can use a chemical or other means to remove the black spots, you should plan on sanding the entire floor prior to application of a high quality (durable) floor finish.

Answer (score 2):

Usually sanding is the only effective treatment, other than living with the spots.

You could try "wood bleach" (usually oxalic acid, not chlorine like laundry bleach) which might or might not help enough. But the directions on the stuff I looked at mention needing to remove the finish before it will work, so you'll be sanding or scraping anyway.

Comment: I have used oxalic acid with great results removing water stains. Yes definitely sand first. It will raise the grain, so a final sanding will be needed in the treated areas.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, looks like I'm going to be sanding the entire floor. Luckly it's only a 12 x 12, I don't have access to a floor sander so I was going to buy a drywall sander to use for this.